# Understanding of Function

Tags: elementary-set-theory

*Example.* 1) Is $f\left( x\right) =\sqrt {x}$ a function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. I think, YES.

2) Is it a function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R^{>0}}$. I think, YES.

3) Is it a function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$. I think, YES.

4) Is it a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. NO. Because negative numbers are not in set of range.

5)Is it a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R^{>0}}$. YES.

6) Is it a function from $\mathbb{R^{>0}}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. YES.

**Can you check my answers?** I'm not sure for 5) and 6).

Comment: 2 looks wrong to me; depends whether you include 0 in the natural numbers or not.

Comment: @JohnHughes Assume $0\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Your answers to 3, 4, and 5 are definitely wrong, try and think about why. (One particular comment: there is a distinction between the *range* and the *codomain*. There can be points in the codomain which are not in the range.) If you take $0 \in \mathbb{N}$ then 2 is wrong as well.

Comment: For 4 (and 5!): the problem is that you can't take a square root of a negative number ... i.e. the negative numbers are not in the *domain*.  And typically, we want functions to be defined for all objects in its domain.  The fact that its range (or image) does not cover its whole co-domain is not an issue.

Comment: If you think 4 is false then 5 should also be false (?)

Comment: For 3, If it's a function from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N$ then it should take each element $n$ of $\Bbb N$ to an element $m$ of $\Bbb N$. Consider the element $2$ of $\Bbb N$. We should have then that $f(2)$ will be in $\Bbb N$. But $f(2) = \sqrt{2}$. Is this in $\Bbb N$?

Comment: For 2, if $0 \in \mathbb N$, then $\sqrt{0} = 0$ would need to be in $\mathbb R^{+}$, which I assume means positive reals, not "nonnegative" reals. So 2 is "No" also.

Comment: The function may take a natural number to a real number, and it may take a real number to a complex number. Think about the cases in which these things happen.

Comment: @JohnHughes You are right. Thanks.

Comment: @lan for 4), for $x=-1$, since $f\left( -1\right) =\sqrt {-1} \not\in\mathbb{R}$, it is not a function.

Comment: for 5) you are right. Now, I'm editing. For $x=0$, since $f\left( 0\right) =\sqrt {0}=0\not\in\mathbb{R^{>0}}$, it is not a function, is it true?

Answer (score 1):

You messed up with the definition of **function**!

$3$ :is wrong. Think about $\sqrt 2$.

$4$ :is correct, but reasoning is wrong. Remember that $\sqrt x$ is  a function from $\Bbb{N}$ to $\Bbb{R}$

$5$: $-1\in \Bbb{R}$ How can $\sqrt x$ be a function of domain $\Bbb{R}$?

Comment: I think you messed up on the numbering.

Comment: @user46944 Corrected the typo! Thanks. Please remove the upvote

Comment: I didn't downvote you.  I downvote very very rarely. Have an upvote for a good answer. :)

Comment: @user46944 Forgive me for my misaccusition. An upvote was extremely kind of you. Thanks again!